# reading filename through command line argument

Tags: java

I came across the following code in a book recently. It says that we can reference a file for instance that we want to read by writing a command line like the first line below. However it is throwing an error with this line. Can someone please advise as I have never come across this before?

Thanks

```
java ShowFile c:/Users/Bosra/Desktop/Sample.txt
import java.io.*;


public class ShowFile
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int i;
    FileInputStream fin;

    //first confirm that a filename has been specified
    if(args.length!=1)
    {
        System.out.println("Usage:ShowFile Filename");
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the error you're getting?

Comment: ShowFile.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        java ShowFile c:/Users/Bosra/Desktop/Sample.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line is the thing you should type in at the command line after compiling the file - it doesn't belong in the file itself.

Comment: @bosra if your code works now you should hit the checkmark below trptcolin's post score to mark it as accepted.